# How to prevent default in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have this simple button in MudBlazor:

```cs
<MudIconButton Class="answer-button" Icon="@_icon" OnClick="OnClick" Color="@_color" 
                   @oncontextmenu="OnContextMenu"
                   @oncontextmenu:preventDefault="true"/>
```

I'm just trying to prevent right click action on button and apply my own logic to it.

I was using [this](https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-use-event-preventdefault-in-blazor.htm) article, but I get this build error

```cs
EventCalendarAnswer.razor(5,36): error RZ10010: The component parameter 'oncontextmenu' is used two or more times for this component. Paramete
rs must be unique (case-insensitive). The component parameter 'oncontextmenu' is generated by the '@oncontextmenu:preventDefault' directive attribute
```

How can I prevent default behaviour in Blazor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the `MudIconButton` inside a `div` and apply the `@oncontextmenu` attribute to the parent element.

```
<div @oncontextmenu="OnContextMenu" @oncontextmenu:preventDefault="true">
    <MudIconButton Class="answer-button" Icon="@_icon" OnClick="OnClick" Color="@_color" />
</div>
```